# Ionic platform add android throws Syntax error for package.json

Tags: android, json, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm building an app with ionic. I've added ios to the platforms with no problem, but when I type `ionic platform add android` I get the following error:

> Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions Adding android project... 
>   Creating Cordova project for the Android platform: Path:
>   platforms/android Package: com.ionicframework.conrem979285 Name:
>   ConRem Activity: MainActivity Android target: android-23 Android
>   project created with cordova-android@5.1.0 Running command:
>   "/Users/Roozbeh/Desktop/ConRem
>   backup/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js"
>     "/Users/Roozbeh/Desktop/ConRem backup" add to body class:
>   platform-android Installing "cordova-plugin-app-event" for android
>   Installing "cordova-plugin-datepicker" for android Installing
>   "cordova-plugin-device" for android Installing
>   "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" for android Dependent
>   plugin "cordova-plugin-device" already installed on android. Dependent
>   plugin "cordova-plugin-app-event" already installed on android.

Your support is needed. If you use the local-notification plugin please support us in order to ensure further development. https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#supporting

Thank you!

> Saving platform to package.json file There was an error opening your
>   package.json file.  SyntaxError: /Users/Roozbeh/Desktop/ConRem
>   backup/package.json: Unexpected token ] at Object.parse (native) at
>   Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:450:27) at Module.load
>   (module.js:356:32) at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12) at
>   Module.require (module.js:366:17) at require (module.js:385:17) at
>   Object.readInPackageJson
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/lib/state.js:14:10)
>   at Object.getPackageJson
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/lib/state.js:23:25)
>   at Object.savePlatform
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/lib/state.js:368:27)
>   at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/cordova.js:83:22
>
> /Users/Roozbeh/Desktop/ConRem backup/package.json: Unexpected token ]
>   (CLI v1.7.14)

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
"name": "conrem",
"version": "1.1.1",
"description": "ConRem: An Ionic project",
"dependencies": {
"gulp": "^3.5.6",
"gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
"gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
"gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
"gulp-rename": "^1.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"bower": "^1.3.3",
"gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
"shelljs": "^0.3.0"
},
"cordovaPlugins": [
"cordova-plugin-device",
"cordova-plugin-console",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar",
"ionic-plugin-keyboard",
"cordova-plugin-datepicker",
],
"cordovaPlatforms": []
}
```

Your system information:

> Cordova CLI: 6.0.0 Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0 Gulp local:
>   Ionic Version: 1.2.4 Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14 Ionic App Lib Version:
>   0.7.0 ios-deploy version: 1.8.4  ios-sim version: 5.0.4  OS: Mac OS X El Capitan Node Version: v4.2.3 Xcode version: Xcode 7.2.1 Build
>   version 7C1002

Can someone please tell me what this syntax error is?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, there, base on your package.json, can I know what's your ionic.project looks like? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your `package.json` there is one extra comma. I think that parsing is very strict and had the same issue before. There must not be a comma after the last item in an array.On the line

```
"cordova-plugin-datepicker",
```

remove the comma at the end.

Comment: Thank you. Solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One of you packages are not supported by Cordova 6. Please check out each of them that they are supported in the targeted CLI version 6.0.0.